# How do I set the initial value of an Angular 9 matRadioButton group?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the simplest possible radio group implemented in Angular Material. This group has been around since it was first written in Angular 2. The app was just upgraded to Angular 9.

```
     <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="choice" class="btn-group">
        <mat-radio-button value="1" color="primary">Choice 1</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="2" color="primary">Choice 2</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="3" color="primary">choice 3</mat-radio-button>
     </mat-radio-group>
```

The value of choice is never null. But when the view is initially rendered no button is selected. How can I get the view to display the selected button when first rendered?

Comment: Please reproduce it here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uic5ce?file=src/app/radio-overview-example.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set choice value at .ts file whichever you want to keep selected as default.

```
choice:string = 2 + "";
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2bzst4-vdt8md?file=src%2Fapp%2Fradio-ng-model-example.html)

Comment: The value is set in ngOnInit()

Comment: There might be issue with something else that causing selection of radio button. Create stackblitz

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gejpj7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Value is type of string. Adding double quotes will solve your issue. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j5zshw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Dhango  I can't change the type of the incoming value, but I can add a property to the component to use instead of the incoming value. I convert it to string in ngOnInit() and convert it back in the radio group's change event.  Not the most elegant solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use [checked] feature.

```
<mat-radio-button [checked]="true"</mat-radio-button>
```